# Getting the error in mollie payment method in magento2.4

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, magento2.4.2

I'm using the mollie payment in magento2.4.2
in checkout page I'm getting this error

```
Message: Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /vendor/mollie/magento2/Plugin/Quote/Api/PaymentMethodManagementPlugin.php on line 67 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-60efde57dabef; Message: Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in vendor/mollie/magento2/Plugin/Quote/Api/PaymentMethodManagementPlugin.php on line 67 at vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, Exception(code: 0): Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in vendor/mollie/magento2/Plugin/Quote/Api/PaymentMethodManagementPlugin.php on line 67 at vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)
```

Comment: Assuming you've not altered the plugin. Have you got any payment methods turned on?

Comment: turned on the payment module and run the commands but still shown the same issue

Comment: Did you configure it in the admin console?

Comment: yes configure the valid credentials